# JSON Marshaller for each action in controller (Grails)

Tags: json, grails, groovy

In grails how to have JSON.registerObjectMarshaller for  each action in controller.

Here is an example

My `User` domain object:

```
String username
String empId
String attendanceID
String password
String firstName
```

in my controller:

```
def myaction1() {
    def user=User.getAll()
    // XXX here i want to return just username and empId
    render user as JSON
}

def myaction2() {
    def user=User.getAll()
    // XXX here i want to return just username and firstName
    render user as JSON
}
```

Comment: What are you attempting to do? Why do you need one for each controller action? What have you tried? What isn't working about what you have tried?

Comment: why don't you just return a map with the content?

Answer (score 5):

While it may be a bit overkill for such as simple domain, and you could likely get away with just returning a `Map` of your data, the question is still valid.

How do you register custom named marshallers?

Typically you will do this inside your `grails-app/conf/BootStrap.groovy` (or a new file `grails-app/conf/CustomMarshallersBootStrap.groovy` if you want to keep things clean). An example of this might look like this:

```
// Bootstrap.groovy
import grails.converters.JSON
import com.example.User

class BootStrap {
  def init = { servletContext ->
    JSON.createNamedConfig("userEmployeeView", {
      JSON.registerObjectMarshaller(User) { User o ->
        return [
          username: o.username,
          empId: o.empId
        ]
      }
    })
    JSON.createNamedConfig("userOtherView", {
      JSON.registerObjectMarshaller(User) { User o ->
        return [
          username: o.username,
          firstName: o.firstName
        ]
      }
    })
  }
  def destroy = { }
}
```

This will register two named marshallers which you can use in your controller(s) like this:

```
// UserController.groovy
package com.example
import grails.converters.JSON

class UserController {
  def action1() {
    def users = User.getAll()
    JSON.use("userEmployeeView") {
      render users as JSON
    }
  }

  def action2() {
    def users = User.getAll()
    JSON.use("userOtherView") {
      render users as JSON
    }
  }
}
```

The above uses named marshllers which allows you to control which JSON representation (actually just a `Map`) will be used when creating the final JSON output.

Hope this helps, and forgive any typos as I wrote this off the top of my head.

Comment: thx for reply I tried your code for action2() it is working fine. But for action1() i am getting all the fields from user domain.

Comment: JSON.createNamedConfig("clientView", {
     JSON.registerObjectMarshaller(User) { User o ->
    return [
      username: o.username,
      firstName: o.firstName,
      lastName: o.lastName
    ]
     }
   })                                                                                                                 To test i  added this in bootstrap  and now i called action2()  with JSON.use("userOtherView")  but i got the json {"username":"xyz.com","firstName":"ABC","lastName":"Admin"}

Comment: It is caching can we to any thing to remove cache