# Retrieving data using Grails Domain returns with a Class Key by default

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I'm working with a Grails query service and I'm using these the `code blocks` to retrieve database rows via a `domain` class.

```
adjustmentCodeList = AdjustmentCode.findAll {
   or {
      ilike('description', "%$filterText%")
      like('id', "%$filterText%")
   }                  
}

adjustmentCodeList = AdjustmentCode.list()

adjustmentCodeList = AdjustmentCode.list(max: count, offset: from)
```

It works *fine* actually, but there is a little problem though. It returns the following `list` (some sensitive `data` are omitted):

```
[
   {
      "class": "rvms.maintenance.AdjustmentCode",
      "id": ...,
      "description": ...,
      "lastUpdateBy": ...,
      "lastUpdateDate": ...,
      "status": ...,
      "statusDate": ...,
      "type": ...
   },
   {
      "class": "rvms.maintenance.AdjustmentCode",
      "id": ...,
      "description": ...,
      "lastUpdateBy": ...,
      "lastUpdateDate": ...,
      "status": ...,
      "statusDate": ...,
      "type": ...
   },
    ...
   {
      "class": "rvms.maintenance.AdjustmentCode",
      "id": ...,
      "description": ...,
      "lastUpdateBy": ...,
      "lastUpdateDate": ...,
      "status": ...,
      "statusDate": ...,
      "type": ...
   }
]
```

It includes the `domain class name`. How can I remove the `class` key using some config? My current solution is to manually remove the `class` key from the list by iterating it inside a loop, removing that key one at a time. But maybe... there is another `Grails`-ly way.

If you want to see the `domain`, it looks like this:

```
package rvms.maintenance

import grails.util.Holders
import groovy.sql.Sql
import oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes
import java.sql.Connection

class AdjustmentCode implements Serializable {
   String id
   String description
   String type
   String status
   Date statusDate
   String lastUpdateBy
   Date lastUpdateDate

   static mapping = {
      table '...'
      version false
      id column : '...'
      description column : '...'
      type column : '...'
      status column : '...'
      statusDate column : '...'
      lastUpdateBy column : '...'
      lastUpdateDate column : '...'
   }

   Map getAdjustmentCodeValues() {
      Map values = [];
      values << [id: this.getId()]
      values << [description: this.getDescription()]
      values << [type: this.getType()]
      values << [status: this.getStatus()]
      values << [statusDate: this.getStatusDate()]
      values << [lastUpdateBy: this.getLastUpdateBy()]
      values << [lastUpdateDate: this.getLastUpdateDate()]

      return values
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Grails way to accomplish this is to customize the marshaller. I've explained how to do this with named marshallers in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28066505/json-marshaller-for-each-action-in-controller-grails) and the same concept applies to your case as well (minus the named portion).

Comment: Like what you've said on your answer there, that is _indeed_ overkill... Maybe some other _straighforward_ method? Though I will use your solution if there's none.

Comment: This is the method for customizing how domain instances become marshalled to JSON in Grails. It's not too bad, really, once you do it, it's done.